# Вставка php переменной в textarea через onclick

Tags: php, jquery

Добрый вечер!
Есть у меня форма, необходимо было организовать вставку  с ссылкой на картинку из папки. Путь до изображение храню в переменной на php (перменная $image).
Если кнопка,

```
var insertToTextarea = function(val) {
var decoded = $("<textarea/>").html(val).text();
$("#text").val(decoded);
}

<button onclick="insertToTextarea('<?=htmlentities($image)?>'); return false;">Вставить</button>
```

В итоге при нажатии на кнопку страница срабатывает, как будто нажали на submit  и ничего не вставляется в textarea, при этом на форме нет ни одного поля submit.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Укажите тип кнопки.

```
<button type="button" onclick="insertToTextarea('<?=htmlentities($image)?>');">Вставить</button>
```

Comment: спасибо) правда код все равно не работает и не вставляет текст, но хотя бы теперь не срабатывает submit)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(documnet).on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('textarea').val('<?=htmlentities($image)?>');
});
```